# django admin login CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, django-forms, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-token

I am building an django application. Everything is working locally. But after uploading it to the production server with `DEBUG=True`. I am getting `csrf` error when trying to login to the admin panel.

[image]

My site is serving on `https://api.example.com`.

My `settings.py`:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://*.example.com"]
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: What if you add the `"https://api. ... .com"` in the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`?

Comment: I did explicitly added api earlier. It does not work either.